# Getting 404 on url <site>/auction/{Some Guid}

Tags: umbraco, umbraco5

A bit new to Umbraco, so this might be a bit of a scattered question.

I'm using 5.1.

I have a document type called Auction with a selected Template called Auction Details

My end goal is to call this controller method on my AuctionSurfaceController

```
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public PartialViewResult Detail(string id)
    {
        Guid auctionId;
        if (Guid.TryParse(id, out auctionId))
        {
            var auction = auctionService.Client.GetAuction(auctionId);
            return PartialView(auction);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

As of this moment when I go to /Auction - it hits this method and passes in "Auction" into the method, when I go to /Auction/{GUID} i just get a 404

Could I please get some general guidance - or requests for clarifications on how to accomplish this. I would very much appreciate it

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the routing is working properly.

Assuming that you're executing from the context of being on an 'auction detail' page, it would then make sense that /{GUID} would serve as the id parameter. (rather than www.mysite.com/auctions/auction/id)

Sometimes this question comes up because there's more than one form on a page, and it's difficult to figure out how umbraco will know which controller Umbraco will post to. This is where the [bind attribute](http://shazwazza.com/post/Umbraco-v5-Surface-Controller-Forms.aspx) comes into play.

However, if you want to use custom routing, because Umbraco 5 is built on MVC, you can always create your own areas and controllers.

Comment: Cheers, a few follow-ups:

You say the routing seems to work correctly - but I'm getting a 404 on auction/{GUID} doesn't that mean that the routing isn't working correctly.

I tried creating a custom route like this:            
   routes.MapRoute(
                "auction", // Route name
                "auction/{id}/", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Auction", action = "AuctionDetails" } // Parameter defaults
            );

But when I use that, I does go into the controller, but seems to be outside of the umbraco context, i.e, the IUmbracoRenderModel was empty.

Comment: To the first point: If you action detail page is 'auctions', then it would make sense that the routing would be www.mysite.com/auctions/id, rather than www.mysite.com/auctions/auction/id. Because this could potentially cause a conflict (say if we had a login partial, and an auction detail on the same page), we use the bind attribute to route. To the second, assuming that you're creating a completely new controller, check out the tutorial here: http://our.umbraco.org/forum/core/umbraco-5-general-discussion/26029-Umbraco-5-How-to-create-a-custom-controller?p=0#comment108786